# Ошибка 'reload() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given' в Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

При выполнении кода:

```
from random import*
from tkinter import*

k1 = random()
k2 = random()

root = Tk()
root.title('Угадайка')
width = 600
height = 600
root.geometry(str(height) + 'x' + str(width) + '200' + '50')
start_number = 0
end_number = 100

start = IntVar

l_number_start = Label(root, text = 'Начальное число:', font = 'Arial')
l_number_start.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

e_number_start = Entry(root, textvariable = start, font = 'Arial')
e_number_start.grid(row = 0, column = 4, columnspan = 2)

l_number_end = Label(root, text = 'Конечное число:', font = 'Arial')
l_number_end.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

e_number_end = Entry(root, textvariable = start, font = 'Arial')
e_number_end.grid(row = 2, column = 4, columnspan = 2)


but_find = Button(root, text = 'Найти!', font = 'Arial')
but_find.grid(row = 4, column = 2, columnspan = 3)


l_number_pc = Label(root, text = 'Число ПК:', font = 'Arial')
l_number_pc.grid(row = 12, column = 2)


but_frame = Frame(root)
but_frame.grid(row = 6, column = 3, columnspan = 3)


but_OK = Button(root, text = 'Угадали! (ノ^∇^)', font = 'Arial')
but_OK.grid(row = 6, column = 3)

but_more = Button(root, text = 'Больше. (ノ_<。)', font = 'Arial')
but_more.grid(row = 8, column = 3)

but_less = Button(root, text = 'Меньше. ╥﹏╥', font = 'Arial')
but_less.grid(row = 10, column = 3)


l_countstep = Label(root, text = 'Попытки:', font = 'Arial')
l_countstep.grid(row = 14, column = 2)

but_restart = Button(root, text = 'Начнём сначала?', font = 'Arial')
but_restart.grid(row = 16, column = 2)


def OK():
          pass

def more():
          pass

def less():
          pass

def reload():
          global k1, k2, l_countstep
          l_number_pc['text'] = ' '
          l_countstep['fg'] = 'black'
          l_countstep['text'] = ' '
          l_countstep = 0
          k1 = start.get()
          k2 = start.get()

def find():
          global k1, k2
          if l_countstep == 1:
                    k1 = start.get()
                    k2 = start.get()
          k = (k1+k2)//2
          l_number_pc['text'] = 'Ваше число:' + str(k)
          l_countstep['text'] = 'Текущее количество шагов:' + str(l_countstep)


but_find.bind('<Button>', find)
but_restart.bind('<Button>', reload)


root.mainloop()
```

Появляется ошибка

```
'reload() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given' в Python
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вызове функции [вы передаете в нее аргумент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805531/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-reload-takes-0-positional-arguments-but-1-was-given-%D0%B2-python-tkinter/805553#comment1274386_805553) `event` в свою очередь она не принимает ее у вас и получается данная ошибка т.е. у вас при вызове функции `reload` значение в ней не прописаны.

Несколько вариантов решения:

1. писать аргумент в функции (переменную `event` вы можете сами задать любую)

   ```
   def find(event):
       ...
   ```

   ---

   ```
   import tkinter as tk
   import random


   def func(event):
       label.config(text=random.randint(1, 500))


   root = tk.Tk()
   label = tk.Label(root)
   label.pack()
   button = tk.Button(root, text='нажми')
   button.bind('<Button>', func)
   button.pack()
   root.mainloop()
   ```
2. вызывать в самой кнопке функцию добавив в значение в кнопке `command`, в данном случае аргументы функции не нужно менять

   ```
   but_restart = Button(root, text='Начнём сначала?', font='Arial', command=reload)
   ```

   ---

   ```
   import tkinter as tk
   import random


   def func():
       label.config(text=random.randint(1, 500))


   root = tk.Tk()
   label = tk.Label(root)
   label.pack()
   button = tk.Button(root, text='нажми', command=func)
   button.pack()
   root.mainloop()
   ```

Comment: Тут непосредственного вызова обработчиков нет, поэтому не "вы передаете", а скорее "tkinter всегда передает в обработчик событий аргумент event".