# Не работает функция, которая связывает вводимые данные с изменением размера фрейма

Tags: python, tkinter

В текстовые поля вводится размер фрейма и по нажатию на пробел размер фрейма меняется. Не получается связать вводимые цифры с изменением размера фрейма. И цвет фрейма почему-то не задается.

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
def bar0():
        tex1.get()=fra['height']

def bar1():
    tex2.get()=fra['width']    

fra=Frame(root,height=500,width=500,bg='lightgreen')
fra.pack()


tex1=Entry(fra,width=20)
tex1.pack()

tex2=Entry(fra,width=20)
tex2.pack()

tex1.bind('<space>',bar0)
tex2.bind('<space>',bar1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import*


def bar0(e):
    fra['height'] = tex1.get()
def bar1(e):
    fra['width'] = tex2.get()


root=Tk()
fra=Frame(root,height=500,width=500,bg='lightgreen')
fra.pack()

fra.pack_propagate(False)

tex1=Entry(fra,width=20)
tex1.pack()

tex2=Entry(fra,width=20)
tex2.pack()

tex1.bind('<space>',bar0)
tex2.bind('<space>',bar1)

root.mainloop()
```

1. Для начала у вас обычная синтаксическая ошибка вы зачем то присваиваете функции считывания текста из `Entry` размер виджета `fra`
2. [При объявлении функции `bind`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/805553/255866) вы должны передавать параметр [`event`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)  функции которую вызываете. Или можете воспользоваться `lambda e: bar0()` чтобы в вашем случае не нужно было бы задавать аргумент функции
3. За изменения размера виджета который скомпонован функцией `pack` существует функция `.pack_propagate(False)` для того чтобы задать элементу фиксированный размер. [Мой ответ на вопрос который вы уже задавали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/824543/255866)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]